# How do I access the overridden ALT tag with the Media Library Media Modify module?

Tags: entities, 10

The Media Library Media Modify module ( https://www.drupal.org/project/media_library_media_modify ) allows one to override a media item's default ALT tag so you can have contextual ALT tags with every use of a media image. How do I programmatically access that tag, or fallback to the original ALT tag when displaying a media image?